# Generate Digest using SHA256 and Signing it with RSA C# Import key as String

Tags: c#, rsa, x509certificate, sha256

I'm new to cryptography.
My goal is to generate a digest from a string with SHA256 and then signing it with RSA.
I've already generated the certificate (Public Key, Private key and the pem certificate) from a 3rd party.

I need to be able to import such Private key (from a string), generate  the SHA256 digest and sign it using RSA. Such should generate a base64 string with an aprox. lenght of 344 chars.

I'll rather use .net native functions without use of 3rd party libraries.
For example:

```
    String password = "hello world";
    var privateKey = "MII..."; //Get just the base64 content.
    var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
    var password_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
       rsa.ImportFromEncryptedPem(privateKey.ToCharArray(),password.ToCharArray());
       decryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt_bytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
       //Display the decrypted plaintext to the console.
       Console.WriteLine("Decrypted new: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedData));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using RSACryptoServiceProvider, RSA instance, opening the pem file directly. I reffered offical documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata?view=net-5.0

Comment: Don't use RSACryptoServiceProvider directly; use RSA.Create().  -- If you've already found SignData, then what do you think isn't working?